# Why can't my installer load the "libglib-2.0.so.0" shared library?

Tags: shared-library

I have to install an agent software for my college intranet.
They provide this .bin file as the installer file.
I type `./file.bin` after going to the right directory.
It says

> error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What is the problem?

I have already done

```
sudo chmod +x file.bin
```

edit:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.3
/usr/share/gdb/gdb/auto-load/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.3-gdb.py
```

output of

```
sudo updatedb && locate libglib-2.0.so.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`libglib-2.0.so.0` should exist on *all* Ubuntu **Desktop** installations -- it will not on a command-line system. Are you running a desktop Ubuntu -- which version?

Comment: 12.04.
what should I do then?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo updatedb && locate libglib-2.0.so.0`?

Comment: updated question.

Comment: Try `sudo ./file.bin` if you trust it; if that doesn't work, a link to the actual bin file would be the best way to troubleshoot this :)

Comment: Well, its on the intranet of my college.
How do I take you to the file? :)
It is a very small one by the way. About half an mb.

Comment: oh and adding sudo didn't work. It gives the same error.
One more thing, while the site says it is a bin file, there is no extension as such shown in the name of the file.
So when I tried ./file.bin it says "no such file". The main error occurs when I try ./file. Should I rename the file to file.bin. Sorry for not telling this before. Thanks

Comment: Can you upload the file to mediafire or something like that?

Comment: sorry for my late reply. One more thing I found out is, the file is for 32 bit Linux. THere is no 64 bit version they offer. Could this be the issue? If not I'll upload it somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: That may be the issue. Please try installing ia32-libs, with `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` and try again.